# How to query an RDF individual for its data properties?

Tags: semantics, rdf, sparql, jena

I have an ontology where `arc_cfp` is an individual of class `Arc`. I would like to know how could I get all the data properties of the individual, given that I have the individual's URI?

Basically, I am doing this:

```
SELECT ?idRef ?name ?src ?dst ?perf
WHERE 
{
    ?x rdf:type http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/1/graph.owl#arc_cfp .
    ?x graph:idRef_arc ?idRef .
    ?x graph:name_arc ?name .
    ?x graph:hasSource ?src .
    ?x graph:hasDestination ?dst .
    ?x graph:hasPerformatif ?perf .
}
```

I am pretty sure, using `rdf:type` is the problem. But, I have no idea what I need to use.

Thanks.

~Codera

Comment: This query tries to retrieve all instances of arc_cfp. Since you say that arc_cfp is itself an instance, this makes no sense. `?x` will never be bound to a value.

Comment: Do you have the rdf and graph prefixes defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a purely exploratory query of the form "give me all the triples about a subject" it should look the following:

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
  <http://example.org/SomeThing> ?p ?o
}
```

This will give you all predicate object pairs associated with the constant URI you pass in.  If you are interesting in incoming as well as outgoing properties you could do the following instead:

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
  { <http://example.org/SomeThing> ?p ?o }
  UNION
  { ?s ?p <http://example.org/SomeThing> }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [DESCRIBE](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#describe) query to grab all the RDF data about a Resource.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
DESCRIBE ?x
WHERE
{
    ?x rdf:type http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/1/graph.owl#arc_cfp .
}
```

P.S. Don't forget to put prefixes in your queries.

Comment: However, there's no canonical implementation of describe, it's left up to the query engine as to what will be returned in the result.  That can be a simple look-up of triples where the variable, in this case ?x, is the subject, or it can be something more complicated like the concise bounded description for the resource.

If there is something specific you want to know about the resource, you're best of querying for exactly that.